# Is there a way to convert SWF into SVG format?

Tags: flash, svg

Is there a way to convert FLA or SWF into SVG format? It can be a Software? Or even a Web convertor? I have tried a few things and none of them worked. All of them seems out of date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are too many features that SWFs support and that the SVG format does not for it to be able to create a valid version of the SWF.

If you just want the symbols, you can open/import/paste them into Adobe Illustrator and then save it as SVG. That'd work. You lose all SWF functionality and advanced features, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response Zeh. Thats too bad. This is gonna create way more work for us. Thanks.

Comment: I know some have made an effort to support exporting a swf to an html+svg+js combination.. but nothing is that feature rich.

Comment: Zeh, how about [Claus' as3swf shape exporters (including SVG)](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export) ? Off topic: thanks for Tweener and all the great articles throughout time ^_^

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza: thanks. Claus' (awesome) as3swf only exports shapes. So it'll work well for native graphics (that's the idea) but not for anything else... it can't really port a SWF to SVG.

Comment: There's a program called Swiffy (by Google) that can convert SWF animations to HTML5, using SVG: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/06/swiffy-convert-swf-files-to-html5.html It doesn't support all types of swf files, though.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is a little old now but for future reference it is possible to convert fla's to swf's using this Flash extension '[Flash2SVG](https://github.com/TomByrne/Flash2Svg)'.

Whilst it isn't reliable for complex animations, and obviously doesn't support ActionScript, for simple animations (or static vectors) it works really well.

Comment: It's close, but doesn't properly support text. It just bakes them down to curves, which works well enough, but you lose the ability to edit it easily.

Comment: The link redirects to https://creative.adobe.com/addons and I can't find "Flash2SVG" in there.

Comment: Replaced the non-working `adobe.com` link with one to the plugin's Github repo.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure If you might have found these, but have a look at http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/ that turns swf into html - might be the closes one can get to swf to svg

Comment: Site says 404 not found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this online application for converting frames to SVG.

Preview, zoom and download.

Check this - http://riaxe.com/online-swf-to-svg-converter/

Comment: 404... URL needs to be updated if this still exists.

Answer (score 2):

Flash Professional CC can export SVG now.

```
File > Export > Export Image , Save as type > SVG Image (*.svg)
```

Comment: This will not export animations, AFAIK.

Comment: Here is a link to Adope Animate Trial: https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/animate?promoid=VY36K4SD&mv=other that I just used to export svg from fla

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/flying-sheep/SWF2SVG seems nicely working. Also online at http://wonderfl.net/c/sPjI .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

> http://swf2svg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Out of all that I tried this one was only one that worked. Thanks for the link!