# Outputting an SVG from an FLA

Tags: objective-c, ios, actionscript-3, flash, svg

Hopefully you guys can help me out. I'm currently developing my first iOS app and need to display Vector graphics, as i understand it, to do this i need to use .SVG files. The plan is to use the [MonkVG](https://github.com/micahpearlman/MonkVG) API to handle the vector implementation inside Cocos2d.

At the moment i have all of the required Vector graphics (some with animation, some without) inside multiple FLA's. I need to be able to export these Vector graphics to multiple .SVG's.

I have tried to use the Flash Professional Extension '[Flash2SVG](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=2422028)' with limited success. It outputs some Vectors but as soon as they become a little more complex the extension crashes. I have also looked at a few webpages that promise to convert to .SVG through an uploader however these seem to return unusable files.

So i guess my question is, does anybody know any other reliable methods to complete a FLA/SWF to .SVG conversion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you want to use the SWF format you should look at Claus' awesome [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) library which includes [shape exporters](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export) including directly to [Objective C](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export-to-Objective-C).

[image: as3swf]
[image: shape export to obj-c]

If you do have the .fla and Illustrator installed, you can try to export an **.fxg** file from Flash, open it in Illustrator and save an SVG from there. The .fxg format supports more features than the older Flash .ai exporter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I was looking into another straight .swf to objective-c library that looked similar to as3swf but it was removed from Github so i'll definately take a look into Claus'.

I did think about .fxg's but my past experience with them wasn't great. Do you know if .fxg holds any animation data like .svg does?

Comment: @GarryBarter I've used .fxg a bit a while back and it does a better job at handling gradients and more complex graphics. Note that some advanced features maybe be supported, but might not translate perfectly so it's worth checking the file after import in illustrator and fixing the paramaters. Regarding animation, not with fxg.I whip my own .jsfl script to get the motion tween parameters. If you don't want to go into .jsfl you can still use the Copy Motion feature and then navigate to the [MotionXML](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/11/04/understanding-flash-cs4-motion-xml/) file and parse that.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll look into using an .fxg but with all the other files on top to carry through animation, it might not be the most streamlined process. I'm attempting to use a lot of legacy Flash animations so it needs to be as simple as possible. Thanks for the help though and i'll definitely try out as3swf.

Comment: @GarryBarter I agree, getting the graphics and animation doesn't seem streamlined. From my point of view I would write a .jsfl script to properly parse the graphics and animation data and export only the data I need into the exact format I need, but that takes time. If you are using Flash CS6 I also recommend having a look at the [CreateJS Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash/flash-to-html5.edu.html). Unfortunately the .jsfl sources are scrambled, but at least it seems to be an option to export graphics and animation into a form of code which can potentially be parsed/used further.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like this question here:

[Is there a way to convert SWF into SVG format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677850/is-there-a-way-to-convert-swf-into-svg-format)

Hope this helps

--EDIT--

Have you tried Adobe Wallaby:

http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i did see this thread. Like i say in my original post, i found an extension that does convert simple fla's but it isn't reliable enough with complex fla's. As this process works to a point, i would think it is in fact possible to convert fla's to an svg format.