# Export a vector shape created in flash to svg

Tags: flash, svg, vector-graphics

Is it possible to export a vector shape created in flash to an svg file for example? Or any other vector format?

If it is possible - how can I do that? Are there any libraries or examples (or both)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert SWF into SVG format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677850/is-there-a-way-to-convert-swf-into-svg-format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of searching - the way to do it is to export the currently selected shape to .fxg and the resulting fxg can be opened in AI with the Place option. Then just choose save as and choose the desired vector format.

Comment: This works in CS6 but fxg support seems to have been deprecated in CC

Comment: @orangesherbert Nothing will automatically convert an animated SWF into an SVG. You either do that with CSS, JavaScript or Canvas; or look at getting Adobe Animate, which is what Flash morphed into - it's for doing exactly that type of thing.

Answer (score 15):

Although it's a little late, you may also want to check out [flash2svg](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=2422028#) by David Belias - it's an MXP extension for Flash that can export Flash vectors to SVG natively.

It's compatible with Flash CS4 & CS5, although no information is immediately available regarding compatibility with other versions.

**UPDATE December 2015**:

Actually, even better than this (as I had issues with this extension myself): <s>[SWF2SVG on wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/c/qic3)</s> *(no longer working)*- this works perfectly and I've used it about a dozen times on a recent project.

**UPDATE December 2017**:

As [@orangesherbert pointed out](http://#comment82014227_21256104), wonderfl.net has been killed off, and most browsers will no longer run Flash content unless explicitly enabled. However, Flash is still the best way to *read* Flash shapes and convert them to SVG shapes, so I created a standalone Windows tool to do just that, which you can download here:

**[Flash2SVG tool](https://www.verynewmedia.com/download/699/)** *(v1.2.1 updated April 2019: Now includes options!)*

It's a Windows installer for a small program that will take any compiled SWF and convert it into an SVG. I still do this *very* regularly myself, so I'm pleased I was able to make it into a standalone executable.

[image: Image SWF2SVG window, featuring options for converting an SWF file to an SVG]

This was built in Flash (*surprise!*) and compiled as an Air for Desktop app. It was signed with the Windows SDK SignTool with a self-issued certificate. If you have issues (or want it for your Mac?), let me know.

(*If anyone wants to still just override their browser settings and allow Flash to run online so they can do this in the browser instead, let me know and I'll find somewhere to host it.*)

Comment: Hi, am I doing something wrong or is wonderfl no longer available?  I navigate to the link (or google) and I just get a splash page.

Comment: It looks like the project has been retired :-(  If anyone has any other ideas please share them

Comment: @orangesherbert Yep, I noticed exactly the same thing. As Flash has effectively been killed online, there is no alternative tool. I have an SWF that I run locally that does the same thing (I can put this online for people to download, but you need a local Flash Player to run it). I've also looked into doing it with JS, but it doesn't have the same capability to read the SWF as Flash inherently does. I've been toying with making an Air app that might do it, but I've never made a standalone one before.

Comment: @orangesherbert I created a standalone program for doing SWF->SVG conversions. See the edits in my answer!

Comment: @indextwo - that tool is a great help, amazing :-)  Unfortunately the tool doesn't seem to work with any of my swf animation files (does this just take the first frame and first layer maybe?)

Comment: @indextwo As mentioned in my reply to your other comment: nothing will automatically convert an animated SWF into an 'animated' SVG (as there's no such thing). You animate an SVG with CSS, JavaScript or Canvas; or look at getting Adobe Animate, which is what Flash morphed into - it's for doing exactly that type of thing, and _should_ be able to deal with your existing Flash animations.

Comment: Fantastic tool! Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sothink SWF decompiler lets you export every frame from the flash swf file as an svg file.

Comment: I can see that it can export shape/font/text resources to SVG, but not frames. Frames can only be exported as .swf or .fla files. (version 7.1)